# Why is my unfurl 'og:image' for gh-pages not showing up in any platform?

Tags: github, linkedin-api, github-pages, slack, skype

Unfurl image of my github pages website not showing up anywhere.

I have tried `<meta property="og:image" content="icon.png"/>` in my header tag
I have also uploaded an image here,
[image]

- The website : https://akibrhast.github.io/Hack-Or-Snooze/
- The Repo : https://github.com/akibrhast/Hack-Or-Snooze

Output as seen in Slack:

- [image]

Output as seen in Skype:

- [image]

Output as seen in Linkedin:

- [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have used:

```html
    <!-- Unfurl Meta -->
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://akibrhast.github.io/Hack-Or-Snooze/"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Hack Or Snooze"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="A Hacker News Clone, with Fresh Viewpoint!"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Hack Or Snooze"/>
<!-- <meta property="og:image" content="icon.png"/> -->
```

**The possible reasons I think,are:**

- You have used the `og:image` tag in comment.
- The directory you have provided is incorrect.(There is no image available at https://akibrhast.github.io/icon.png instead the image is at https://akibrhast.github.io/Hack-Or-Snooze/icon.png)
  **Try copying the following code and replace with the old one:**

```html
<!-- Unfurl Meta -->
<meta property="og:url" content="https://akibrhast.github.io/Hack-Or-Snooze/"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Hack Or Snooze"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="A Hacker News Clone, with Fresh Viewpoint!"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Hack Or Snooze"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="./icon.png"/>
```

**I hope this will work.**
And the image you have given in the repository settings is shown on Social Media, when your repository link is shared(i.e., https://github.com/akibrhast/Hack-Or-Snooze) .[image: Repository Og Pic]

 And remember to follow the image requirements of LinkedIn,as mentioned [here.](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin)

- Max file size: 5 MB
- Minimum image dimensions: 1200 (w) x 627 (h) pixels
- Recommended ratio: 1.91:1

Comment: @iambdm , where/how did you get that last image from?

Comment: @imbdm, changing the path to
`<meta property="og:image" content="./icon.png"/>` fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. The last image I got when I pasted your repository link on facebook, and when I checked the source code of your [repository](https://github.com/akibrhast/Hack-Or-Snooze), there was the [og:image](https://repository-images.githubusercontent.com/307276290/2b2a8080-6737-11eb-84eb-2b8351a2bfc3) .

Answer (score 0):

The url for **og:image** needs to be the full url, relative ones are not allowed, so you would need add:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://github.com/akibrhast/Hack-Or-Snooze/blob/master/icon.png">
```